# Multiple MySQL catalogs on EMR/PrestoDB

Tags: mysql, emr, presto

I'm able to create a catalog called mysql on my EMR by using the `presto-connector-mysql` configuration options on EMR.

*However*, I'd like to connect to multiple mysql datasources.  Adding a 2nd datasource to `/etc/presto/conf/catalog` and then doing a `restart presto-server` isn't quite right, because while I can query the mysql datasource correctly and the 2nd catalog shows up, querying a table there gives:

`Query 20170407_040307_00008_qjgse failed: No nodes available to run query`

Is there a way to reset the whole cluster?  Do I need to install the new catalog on all the nodes?

Comment: I am if you were able to solve the problem of specifying multiple classifications for the same connector type in the ERM configuration. I can push the configuration to nodes post-creation as the answer states, but that is not a scalable solution imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the new catalog in `/etc/presto/conf/catalog` on all of the nodes, and then restart Presto. Then it should work fine for you.